# tensorflow momentum part of variable not initialized?

Tags: tensorflow

tensorflow is telling me that the momentum part of a variable is uninitiated when I use the momentum optimizer. When I use the gradientDescent optimizer things work fine.

Here is a relevant part of the stack trace:

```
tensorflow.python.framework.errors.FailedPreconditionError: Attempting to use uninitialized value fc3/biases/Momentum
     [[Node: Momentum/update_fc3/biases/ApplyMomentum = ApplyMomentum[T=DT_FLOAT, _class=["loc:@fc3/biases"], use_locking=false, _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](fc3/biases, fc3/biases/Momentum, Momentum/learning_rate, gradients/fc3/logits_grad/tuple/control_dependency_1, Momentum/momentum)]]
Caused by op u'Momentum/update_fc3/biases/ApplyMomentum', defined at:
...
    train_op = vgg.optimizer.minimize(vgg.loss, global_step=vgg.global_step)
```

I think the code is correct, it defines the ops for all layers before the initialize all variables op, etc. If not the GradientDescent optimizer wouldn't work right?

Following up on @etarion comment, here is a sketch of the code, starts with

```
def train(args):
    datareader = # object to read data - no tensorflow code/import

    with tf.Graph().as_default():
        with_graph(datareader, args)
```

then with_graph does

```
def with_graph(datareader, args):
    num_outputs = datareader.num_outputs()
    img_orig = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=datareader.features_placeholder_shape())
    img_vgg16 = preprocess.imgbatch_2_vgg16(imgs=img_orig, channel_mean=8.46)
    labels_placeholder = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=(None, num_outputs))
    vgg = vgg16(imgs=img_vgg16, weights=None, sess=None, trainable=args.trainable, stop_at_fc2=args.fc2)
    add_loss(vgg, labels_placeholder, num_outputs, args)
    add_optimizer(vgg, args)

    sess = tf.Session(config=tf.ConfigProto(intra_op_parallelism_threads = 12))    
    init = tf.initialize_all_variables()
    sess.run(init)


    validation_imgs_orig, validation_labels = datareader.get_validation_set()
    validation_imgs_vgg16 = sess.run(img_vgg16, {img_orig: validation_imgs_orig})
    validation_feed_dict = {img_vgg16:validation_imgs_vgg16,
                            labels_placeholder:validation_labels}    
    train_op = vgg.optimizer.minimize(vgg.loss, global_step=vgg.global_step)

    print("Starting training.")
    sys.stdout.flush()
    for step_number in range(3):
        t0 = time.time()
        train_imgs, train_labels = datareader.get_next_minibatch()
        train_feed_dict = {img_orig: train_imgs,
                           labels_placeholder:train_labels}
        sess.run(train_op, feed_dict=train_feed_dict)        
        print("step %3d took %.2f sec." % (step_number, time.time()-t0))
        sys.stdout.flush()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The gradient descent optimizer does not have internal variables, the momentum one has. Somehow you don't initialize the state of the momentum (can't tell why exactly without the code). Ways to do that are initializing *all* variables right before you run the graph (after you added the optimizer to the graph), or, if you want to be explicit in what you initialize, use the [get_slot_names()/get_slot()](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.10/api_docs/python/train.html#Optimizer.get_slot_names) methods of the optimizer to get the Variables that make up the optimizer's internal state.

Comment: Hi @etarion, I updated my post to have more code, I'll use the get_slot_names if I have to, but does what I have look wrong?

Answer (score -1):

The problem is I was defining the training op from the optimizer minimize function after initializing all the variables - once I moved that in front of initialize all variables it worked.